# What's the best(right) way to write a polling method (with Typescript & AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to write a polling method that polls a server periodically to check whether a zip file has already been created or not.

What I want to accomplish are the following:

1. Calls(ajax) an API that creates a zip file on server
2. Calls(ajax) another API that checks if the zip file has already been created (polling method)
3. Some subsequent process

Here is my code snippet ↓

```
var success: boolean = false;
//1. requests a server to create a zip file
this.apiRequest.downloadRequest(params,ApiUrl.URL_FOR_DOWNLOAD_REQUEST)
.then((resObj) => {
       var apiRes: IDownloadService = resObj.data;
       if (apiRes.status[0].statusCode == "000") {
            success = true;
       } else {
            //Error
       }
}).then(() => {
       if (success) {
         //2. polls the server to check if the zip file is ready
         <- Polling method↓ ->
         this.polling(params).then((zipUrl) => {
                    console.log(zipUrl); //always logs zipUrl
                    //some subsequent process...
         });
       }
});
```

Could anyone give some examples of polling method that would work in this case?

Added:

```
private polling(params: any): ng.IPromise<any> {
            var poller = () => this.apiRequest.polling(params, ApiUrl.URL_FOR_POLLING);
            var continuation = () => poller().then((resObj) => {
                var apiRes: IDownloadService = resObj.data;
                if (apiRes.zipFilePath == "") {
                    return this.$timeout(continuation, 1000);
                } else {
                    return apiRes.zipFilePath;
                }
            })
            var result: ng.IPromise<any> = continuation();
            return result;          
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically abstract the methods out as shown below:

```
let poll = () => this.apiRequest.downloadRequest(params,ApiUrl.URL_FOR_DOWNLOAD_REQUEST)

let continuation = () => poll().then((/*something*/)=> {
 /*if still bad*/ return continuation();
 /*else */ return good;
})

continuation().then((/*definitely good*/));
```

## Update

As requested in the comment below:

> return this.$timeout(continuation, 1000);

This is needed to get angular to kick off a digest cycle.

Comment: The added is my actual polling method that polls server every 1 sec to check if requested zip file has already been created and is working fine.
My question here is why the method behaves differently with and without "return" right before this.$timeout(continuation, 1000); 
Could you help me understand on this?

Comment: Actually what I wanted to know is that how the polling method behaves when with and without "return" right before "this.$timeout(continuation, 1000);" .

Comment: @basarat I like that, but what is the purpose of the last line: continuation().then((/*definitely good*/));